# How to use Selenium elements to wait, check, click on without finding the elements again?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am new to Selenium and was using Telerik free testing framework before. Problem is I am not able to understand, how to use elements which are already identified with [FindsBy] to wait, check and click on.

ex:

```
    [FindsBySequence]
    [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "container-dimpanel")]
    [FindsBy(How = How.CssSelector , Using = ".btn.btn-primary.pull-right")]
    public IWebElement UpdateButton { get; set; }

    internal void ClickUpdateButton(TimeSpan timeout)
    {
        new WebDriverWait(_driver, timeout).
            Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.CssSelector(id));
        UpdateButton.Click();
    }
```

I want my code to wait for update button to be visible and then click on it. But I want to just pass the UpdateButton element rather than using By selector.

- not sure if UpdateButton.Enabled will wait until its visible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an expected condition for visibility that accepts a WebElement:
https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#visibilityOf-org.openqa.selenium.WebElement-

`Until` also returns the element being waited for, so you can combine this into one line:

```
internal void ClickUpdateButton(TimeSpan timeout)
{
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(_driver, timeout);
    wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(UpdateButton)).click();
}
```

However, in my frameworks I usually add a helper function that does this, as it get's used so much. You can also do similar things with wait until clickable, etc. and have methods that accept a WebElement or a By:

```
public WebElement waitThenClick(WebElement element) 
{
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(_driver, timeout);
    return wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(UpdateButton)).click();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for providing the answer. Unfortunately, C# does not have visibilityOf() method in ExpectedConditions. Instead it has ElementToBeClickable().

Comment: It looks like the library has one called ElementIsVisible: https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_ExpectedConditions_ElementIsVisible.htm

Answer (score 2):

The C# client doesn't have a builtin condition to check the visibility for a proxied `WebElement`.

Moreover the expected condition `ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible` checks that the element is displayed but doesn't check that the element is visible from a user perspective.

So the quickest and most reliable way is to retry the click in a waiter until success:

```CSharp
Click(UpdateButton, 5);
```

```CSharp
static void Click(IWebElement element, int timeout = 5) {
    var wait = new DefaultWait<IWebElement>(element);
    wait.IgnoreExceptionTypes(typeof(WebDriverException));
    wait.PollingInterval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10);
    wait.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeout);
    wait.Until<bool>(drv => {
        element.Click();
        return true;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this function I've written to test for an element, you can just pass in the name. It will return a bool and you could use a loop to wait for the elements to be present.

```
static public bool verify(string elementName)
{
    try
    {
        bool isElementDisplayed = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(elementName)).Displayed;
        return true;
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }
    return false;
}
```